# No URLs in dashboard

Tags: installation, dashboard

After installing Drupal I cannot use the dashboard menu because none of the URLs are found. I cannot google my way to find a solution to this so.

Comment: What is your actual question? Also, is this about Drupal 5?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the .htaccess file exists in the Drupal root. Sometimes people unzip/untar or copy paste Drupal directories and this file is excluded by some operating systems and file transfer programs.

Drupal 7 .htaccess: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.htaccess?h=7.x

Drupal 8.2.x .htaccess: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/.htaccess

This is usually the cause of what you report.

Otherwise, this could be an issue with how Apache or IIS is setup to serve your Drupal site. Since you can really get in the weeds with server configurations such as Apache, it is recommended you use something like [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop) or [DrupalVM](http://www.drupalvm.com) to install and run a Drupal site locally, so you can sidestep issues and run a local site under generally accepted best practices for a LAMP stack tuned for Drupal.